# ERROR ITMS-90475: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires launch storyboard in bundle 'com.companyname.appname.'"

Tags: ios, swift2, objective-c

Estoy tratando de publicar una aplicación en AppStore y me sale este error:

> ERROR ITMS-90475: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires launch storyboard in bundle 'com.companyname.appname.'"

¿Alguien sabe lo que este error realmente significa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes especificar como tu aplicación debe gestionar `multitasking`, activa la opción `Requires full screen`.

Si no quieres manejar multitasking, solo desactivalo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Respuesta en inglés: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557783/invalid-bundle-error-requires-launch-story-board**